# Audacity snap [pango_font_description_set_size assertion 'size >=0' failed]

Tags: 20.04, xorg, snap, wayland, audacity

I'm on Ubuntu version 20.04.1 LTS, and Gnome 3.36.3

Running audacity from command-line gives me the following error:

```bsh
Attempting to connect to Audacity failed...retrying
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
ALSA lib seq.c:935:(snd_seq_open_noupdate) Unknown SEQ default
ALSA lib control.c:1373:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL hw:0
ALSA lib control.c:1373:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL hw:0
Expression 'stream->capture.pcm' failed in '/build/audacity/parts/audacity/src/lib-src/portaudio-v19/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 4611
ALSA lib control.c:1373:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL hw:0
ALSA lib control.c:1373:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL hw:0

(audacity:42362): Pango-CRITICAL **: 18:21:42.969: pango_font_description_set_size: assertion 'size >= 0' failed
(audacity:42362): Pango-CRITICAL **: 18:21:42.969: pango_font_description_set_size: assertion 'size >= 0' failed
(audacity:42362): Pango-CRITICAL **: 18:21:42.969: pango_font_description_set_size: assertion 'size >= 0' failed
(audacity:42362): Pango-CRITICAL **: 18:21:42.969: pango_font_description_set_size: assertion 'size >= 0' failed
(audacity:42362): Pango-CRITICAL **: 18:21:42.969: pango_font_description_set_size: assertion 'size >= 0' failed
...
...

---- Same thing repeats for several lines -----
```

Also tried both Xorg and Wayland session getting the same result.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to fix this error in the snap package, but a workaround would be to install the slightly older version (`apt - v2.3.3, snap - v2.4.1` as of 17.08.2020) of Audacity from `apt`.

Open a terminal and enter the following commands.

```
sudo snap remove audacity
sudo apt install audacity
```

Comment: Yeah I know installing it from apt works, but I needed the one from snap to work, thanks for your comment

Comment: @midrizi Is there any particular reason you need the snap version? Does the new version in the snap have some new feature? (I have not used Audacity, so I don't know)

Comment: Switching between apps seems to reset the focus, while snap package didn't (when it was working)